# Converting PHP to Java

Tags: java, php, inheritance, constructor

I have worked with PHP for 6 years now and am certified in it, but lately I have decided that I should learn Java, as I worked a lot with the Zend framework, which is inspired by Java, but now I have what is, perhaps, a stupid problem with Java.

In PHP I would do this:

```
class Cool
{
    protected $_name;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    function showName()
    {
        echo "{$this->_name} is a cool guy";
    }
}

class Bad extends Cool
{
    function showName()
    {
        echo "{$this->_name} is a bad guy";
    }
}

$bad = new Bad("jhon");
// prints jhon is a bad guy
```

Since Java doesn't inherit constructors, what would be the best way to do something like this in Java?  Will I have to think of a different type of patterns to solve this kind of thing?

I appreciate the help since I'm really new to Java and since I use this kind of thing a lot I'd like to know if there's any cool way to do it in Java.  I need to use it on a new project I'm getting assigned to.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you'll have to write a constructor for each class and call [`super()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) to use the parent's constructor. If you don't want to alter the constructor, all you need to do in the subclass constructor is call `super()`.

In this case, `Bad` would look like this:

```
public class Bad extends Cool {
    public Bad(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    // Any other additions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors aren't inherited directly as members on the subclass, but any non-private constructors will be accessible via a corresponding `super` call from within the subclass, which works just as well.  When you don't want to modify any behavior of the superclass's constructor, just add a version to your subclass that takes the same parameter(s) and calls the `super` version.

So you could write the above code in Java as:

```
public class Cool {
    protected String name;

    public Cool(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void showName() {
        System.out.println(this.name + " is a cool guy");
    }
}

public class Bad extends Cool {
    public Bad(String name){
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void showName() {
        System.out.println(this.name + " is a bad guy");
    }
}

Cool bad = new Bad("jhon");
bad.showName(); // prints jhon is a bad guy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that constructors are not inherited, you would need to do:

```
public class Bad extends Cool {
 public bClass( String name ) {
   super( name );
 }
}
```

This will call the supers constructor, which would be the parent's constructor.